# Formatting problem

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

Sometimes formatting symbols are not recognized immediately after a TeX expression, as in the [fourth paragraph here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4686/sampling-with-non-uniform-costs/4697#4697).  (This is not the only instance I have encountered.  A work-around is to put a single linefeed between the TeX and the ensuing characters.)

Here's the offending text:

`**The error rate depends on the state of the population**.  I interpret the problem to require that the *expected* error size be assured of not exceeding the limit $k$  *no matter what the state of the population may be.*  We cannot remove the word "expected" here, because (except for nearly exhaustive samples), the maximum error size can be arbitrarily close to 1 for large populations.`

In the original the last group of asterisks, which should italicize a phrase, is rendered literally.  (It is interesting that they successfully create italicization within the 'PRE' block here!)  Finally, here is a copy of that paragraph.  It looks fine in editing mode preview but it is still rendered incorrectly in the standard view:

**The error rate depends on the state of the population**.  I interpret the problem to require that the *expected* error size be assured of not exceeding the limit $k$ *no matter what the state of the population may be.*  We cannot remove the word "expected" here, because (except for nearly exhaustive samples), the maximum error size can be arbitrarily close to 1 for large populations.

Comment: can you provide an excerpt in a `<pre>` block of specifically what you mean? I viewed the post but I'm unclear..

Comment: @Jeff I successfully reproduced the problem by editing this question.

Comment: ... and it seems like the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding an extra space is a workaround for now (I added an extra space to your example above).